# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deployContract')

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const userstorage = await hre.ethers.deployContract("userstorage");

  await userstorage.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    `deployed to ${userstorage.target}`
  );
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

currently using ethers v6.11.0

Comment: This might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/112890/91017.